# How to increase user defined variables storage size

Tags: mysql, json

I have one procedure which return very large size of JSON, but looks like after certain size output variable is not able to receive full output, it works fine for small data, i checked in source SP and seems till assignment that SP's variable able to hold data correctly.

```
CALL MyDATA('',@out_var);
SELECT @out_var;
```

Is there any storage limit for mysql user defined variables?

I am using MySQL version:8.0.11

Comment: The size of the result is limited by `max_allowed_packet`.

Comment: what is the @out_var defined your procedure

Comment: Is JSON variable.